# Left side bar is not displaying .after made changes in base folder's files

Tags: magento-1.9

In my website Left side bar is not dislaying after deleted the code line
""

`<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl($this->getImgSrc()) ?>"
<?php if(!$this->getLinkUrl()): ?> 
title="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgAlt()) ?>"
<?php endif; ?> 
alt="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgAlt()) ?>" />` """
,

In the path **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/callouts/left_col.phtml.**
After adding the same code then also its not displaying.
Once i tried the before the same i deleted and adding the same code that time its displaying properly.Now its not displaying.

If I do changes in base folder files will it affect like that?.

please anybody Help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a file in checkout folder. this phtml in callouts folder

```
 <div class="block block-banner">
        <div class="block-content">
            <?php if(strtolower(substr($this->getLinkUrl(),0,4))==='http'): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getLinkUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgAlt()) ?>">
            <?php elseif($this->getLinkUrl()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl($this->getLinkUrl()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgAlt()) ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl($this->getImgSrc()) ?>"<?php if(!$this->getLinkUrl()): ?> title="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgAlt()) ?>"<?php endif; ?> alt="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgAlt()) ?>" />
            <?php if($this->getLinkUrl()): ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Write this code in **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\callouts\left_col.phtml**